# How to export and overload function argument list with tuples of different lengths in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, tuples

Unfortunately in Typescript 4.5.4 the following overload with different tuples of different length does not work for me:

```
export function f<T1>    (t: [T1])   : any { ... }
export function f<T1,T2> (t: [T1,T2]): any { ... }
```

while the usage would be (in another file)

```
f(["hello"])
f(["hello", "world"])
```

Typescript gives me:

> TS2323: Cannot redeclare exported variable 'f'.

Any ideas on a workaround without introducing multiple function names (on top level)?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902789/how-can-i-export-an-overloaded-function-in-typescript) question is similar, but the answer does not seem to work anymore (EDIT: it works, I misused) and is not exactly the same (in my question Tuple type is given which may or may not have impact on the right answer).

Comment: Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=87&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWIDwAqAjAHwAUMAXHANrEC6AlNcQLABQoksiqG2uBISIAaOAQBM5KrWJjJTFhI5do8ZOiw5EFajQCGKAJ704AH1qGjYq0zgBvDnDiYEcCgDoANsBQBzGAALOABeMLgJRgcnZzgoYBgkKFwYGiJ6GIBfGPjE5LhUgAYM9mz2Dg4EMhoYKCRgOwB6Rt5NAXwAIwgIH0NpPS6e4ENFOEHe3DIAaiI4CAA3YCgvCH0AE0ZK6tE4AHJ4td2mlo1+bSEUJABbDqWxAGdazH9+2kubu7hHqGe-Ue-fu4ZnNFstVhsgA) though I'm not sure you need the extra overhead of overloads. The answer you linked to still holds... overloads should only implement the function once with multiple type signatures.

Comment: Does this issue happen only for 4.5.4 ? I tried with 4.5.5, your code seems working.

Comment: @pilchard Oh wow, maybe I was missing that one: "overloads should only implement the function once" -> I implemented the function multiple times.

Comment: @ABOS I think pilchard pointed out what I messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you need the extra overhead of overloads, but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57902840/13762301) you linked to still holds – overloads should declare multiple type signatures but only implement the function once.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWIDwAqAjAHwAUMAXHANrEC6AlNcQLABQoksiqG2uBISIAaOAQBM5KrWJjJTFhI5do8ZOiw5EFajVQBrFBADuKenAA+tQ8bNjbp84zgBvDnDiYEcCgDoAG2AUAHMYAAs4AF4YuAkXd3ZPTyhgGCQoXBgaInoPOABffNT0zLhsgAY89iL2DnyEMhoYKCRgJjgAek7eTQF8ACMICCCAQxRpPSGR4HHFOGmx3DIAaiI4CAA3YCgAiFGAE0Z6pJ0csQByVIOLju7e-m0hFCQAWwGdsQBnFsxQydoL3enzgPygfxC8zBEN8aw2212+yOJ08jXOcCuwBuYgkTA49zgAD1iSTSST8T04AA5CDwnZ7Q5wV6jGBocLAL7lcKYTloUYBAJ+CnJOAAeQRDIOcHWEB8EkuuhsKCMTnmjjMFzEIVG2y5wEQIz2JhhOyg0CF7AJIoAglAQm9gvBZeUAJ5gfUXGhAj5Qb6-UJib07egXLyc4zwUZfL6YEIoUYDILlWlgUZQUavNI7DY+GBuj36ZV2cwXC1WkVwADKEAyaH14SjcAAzHBgEFMygYGQvi4Bkh4DA0yE0nB+UbOTgAi7pWXKSLxfSkXEc3EFTJCyr7HB1c5qDvNXBtbqIvqEIbTCaoGaoLOK8lbfaO07c-mMV63j6-eCA3Ag1AQ2Gv4QJG0axvGib6jAKZphmWZQCuebum+O4OEWqqlsKd7JNWtb1o2LZtsAT7dr2-blEOI5jqYE4oFOcR+EAA)

```
export function f<T1>(t: [T1]): T1
export function f<T1, T2>(t: [T1, T2]): T2
export function f(t: [unknown] | [unknown, unknown]) {
  if (t.length === 2) {
    return t[1]
  }
  return t[0]
}


  f([true]) // function f<boolean>(t: [boolean]): boolean (+1 overload)

  f([1, 'red']) // function f<number, string>(t: [number, string]): string (+1 overload)

  f([1, 'red', 2])
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  No overload matches this call.
//    Overload 1 of 2, '(t: [unknown]): unknown', gave the following error.
//      Argument of type '[number, string, number]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[unknown]'.
//        Source has 3 element(s) but target allows only 1.
//      Overload 2 of 2, '(t: [unknown, unknown]): unknown', gave the following error.
//        Argument of type '[number, string, number]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[unknown, unknown]'.
//          Source has 3 element(s) but target allows only 2.
```